# Integrating matrix minors without a loop in Matlab

Tags: loops, matlab, matrix, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate all the 2x2 matrices A(i-1:1,j-1:j) in Matlab without using a loop. Right now I am doing in a loop but it is extremely slow.  The code is shown below:

```
A=rand(100)
t=linespace(0,1,100);
for i=2:length(A)
   for j=2:length(A)
       A_minor=A(i-1:i,j-1:j);
       B(i,j)=trapz(t(j-1:j),trapz(t(i-1:i),A_minor));
   end
end
```

I'd like to do this without using loops to speed up computation.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Matlab Image Processing Toolbox, you may be able to use **blockproc** to do what you want.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/blockproc.html

To use blockproc, you will need to define a function that does what you want to be executed on each position in the matrix. Note that the way you are using trapz makes things a little trickier (passing the x-values in - if you can get away without them, you can simplify the code) - here I run trapz without them and scale the results.

```
% Data
foo = rand(100);
t = linspace(0,1,100);

% Execute blockproc on the indexes
fooproc = blockproc(foo, [2, 2], @(x) trapz(trapz(x.data)));
fooproc = fooproc * (t(2)-t(1))^2; % re-scale by the square of the step size
```

If you need to pass the x values to trapz, the solution gets a bit trickier.

Comment: Could you explain further?

Comment: You can use this function to execute a function on each block of a matrix. You can specify whether you want the blocks to be overlapping or disjoint. 

So, in your case, you want to execute a function on each 2x2 block of the matrix. I'll edit my answer to provide more details.

Comment: Could you edit the code to incorporate overlapping blocks?  I can't figure it out.  Thanks!

Comment: @BabakP - Hmm - I though blockproc did overlapping blocks, but as I look at the documentation, I'm can't seem to find how either. :P It looks like I was mistaken. I'll add another answer with another approach.

Answer (score 0):

As trapz is a simple function (especially on a 2x2 matrix), you can just compute the result directly, without calling a function:

```
t = linspace(0,1,100); % Note that this is a step size of 0.010101
A = rand(100);
B = nan(size(A));

Atmp = (A(1:end-1,:) + A(2:end,:))/2;
Atmp = (Atmp(:,1:end-1) + Atmp(:,2:end))/2;

B(2:end,2:end) = Atmp * (t(2)-t(1))^2;
```

This should give you the exact same result as your *for* loop, but much faster.